# VueJS: Updating data from method makes the properties synced

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm using VueJS. There is a very simple case. I have the following as data:

```
  data: {
    a: {"name":null},
    b: {"name":null}
  }
```

I am taking user input and attaching it to 'a' using v-model.

```
<input type="text" v-model="a.name">
```

Then I have a method, which when triggered, should copy the value from a to b.

```
save() {
  this.b=this.a
}
```

This works fine the first time, but once I've triggered the method, both a and b are permanently synced. Why is that happening and how can I keep a and b separate unless the save method is triggered. So, after the method is triggered once, then everytime you update a, it's updating b as well which should not happen.

The bellow JS Bin shows the issue:

https://jsbin.com/kofobifego/1/edit?html,js,console,output

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is because objects are reference types in JS.Try the following code.

```
save() {
  this.b.name = this.a.name
}
```

**Simplified** explanation:
When you create an object in JavaScript, a space in the memory is reserved for that object. What you assign to variable is a **reference** to that object - think of it as a path / link to the place in memory where an object exists. Therefore the code below...

```
this.b = this.a
```

... takes the reference that **this.a** holds and assigns a copy of it to the **this.b**. Now both **this.a** and **this.b** have a reference assigned, but it leads to the same object in memory. This is why modifying **this.a** also "modifies" **this.b**.

Please refer to [this article](https://codeburst.io/explaining-value-vs-reference-in-javascript-647a975e12a0) for more detailed explanation of the topic.